# Hex to binary using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, binary, hex, converters

Is it possible to convert a Hexdump to binary using VBS?
I made a program that reads any file as Byte array, then it converts it to Hex.
In output Hexdump looks like this

```
00 00 00 0A 4D
```

til the end.
Now i want to know if i can convert it back to binary and execute it using a VBScript.
I will appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
hexstr = "00 00 00 0A 4D"

hexarr = Split(hexstr)
ReDim binarr(UBound(hexarr))

For i = 0 To UBound(hexarr)
  binarr(i) = Chr(CInt("&h" & hexarr(i)))
Next

binstr = Join(binarr, "")
```

Comment: Having an off day? You cannot `CInt` a string that represents a byte in Hex in VBScript. (And you missed a `)` on the `ReDim` line)

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Sure you can. You just need to prepend the string with `&h`, which is what I forgot. Fixed.

Comment: Ooh, nice solution. I was thinking about creating a dictionary with all hex pairs in 256 entries and their Chr'd Int value. Then with each pair, you do a lookup in the dictionary and use the item in the array. But this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array out of the hex dump, prepend with "&h", then write the binary file:

```
Dim File : Set File = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("Jim.bin")
data = Array(&h00,&h00,&h00,&h0A,&h4D)

for each x in data
File.write chr(x)
next

File.Close
```